# Power series behaviour in edge of convergence disc

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I have to find the radius of convergence of the following complex series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(1-i)^n}$$

The radius of convergence I get its $R = \sqrt{2}$, now I have to examine what happens with this series on this edge, that is where $|z| = \sqrt{2}$.

Here is where my problems start, the absolute convergence doesn't help me as it doesn't converge absolutely, any tips on what path to follow on?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z|=\sqrt2$, then$$\left|\frac{z^n}{(1-i)^n}\right|=\left|\frac z{1-i}\right|^n=1,$$and therefore your series diverges; otherwise, you would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n}{(1-i)^n}=0$.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

The series in question is the power series representation if the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\tfrac{z}{1-i}}=\frac{1-i}{1-i-z}$$
this function is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1-i\}$ and $z_0=i-z$ is a pole. So, as it was pointed out before, $|f(z)|\xrightarrow{z\rightarrow z_0}\infty$. At any other point in the boundary if the disk of convergence things are fine, as $f$ can be extended analytically.

---

Of course, the power series converges uniformly in any closed sets inside $B(0;\sqrt{2})$ as foretold by [classical results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) of convergence of power series.